# Word for flower that blooms and wilts in one day

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for the botanical term for a flower that blooms and wilts in the same day.

Comment: For a metaphor you could use "daylily".

Comment: Fugacious flowers. Check the entry in the [collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fugacious), American, 2nd entry.

Comment: Please read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking Good Luck.

Answer (score 5):

**Fugacious** (adjective)

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fugacious

Fugacious (in American)

> 2. (Botany)
>      falling soon after blooming, as some flowers

Reference: [LIBRARY NEW YORK BOTANICAL GARDEN](https://archive.org/stream/papersonbotany08stou/papersonbotany08stou_djvu.txt)

> One of these plants was called Liriosphodelus phoeniceus and Lobel states that the names "Hemerocalis" and "Ephemerum" were commonly applied to this particular plant because of the fact that the fugacious flowers last for scarcely a day. Of the flower behavior of the other type mentioned under the name Liriosphodeluslit tens liliflorus, the Lemon Daylily of today, Lobel makes no mention.

Reference: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fugacious

> In this way Masdevallia, Sobralia, and other ***fugacious flowers*** may be used for decorative purposes for two evenings at least, but in the absence of immersion they would wither in a very short time. O'Brien, James

Couple of more entries on [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&biw=1326&bih=637&ei=yASPXL7bCoiAvwTjo6HgCg&q=%22fugacious%20flowers%22&oq=%22fugacious%20flowers%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i30.3733.3733..4034...0.0..0.85.85.1......0....1..gws-wiz.dQqquWMoqXs).

---

Few other terms, which describes ephemeral life span of flowers are as follows:

**Nyctigamous**

> A reference to flowers that open at night and close during the day; nygtigamy.

**[Nyctinasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyctinasty), Nytinastic, Nyctinastism**

Reference: https://wordinfo.info/unit/2563/ip:5/il:N

> 2. Orientation movements of plants during the night.
>
>    > Nastic movements of plant organs in response to the changes in light and temperature that occur between day and night (and vice versa). Examples are the opening and closing of many flowers and the folding together of the leaflets of clover and other plants at night.